# Ternary Operator for grid color in array to be a specific color (multiple conditions) Java

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, grid-layout, ternary-operator

I am constructing a GUI to display a map using GridLayout and would like to display it in different colors. As of right now, I have it so if the number in the array equals 0, the color of that specific square will be black. If it's any other number, it will be gray. As you can see, that would be a very boring grid map to look at. Is there a way to take this line of code and make it so if each number could represent a color? For example, I would like 0 to equal black, 1 to equal gray, 2 to equal blue, 3 to equal red, 4 to equal green, etc.. This is what I have now.

Color color = data[r][c] == 0 ? Color.BLACK : Color.gray;

I know I could just use an if statement to determine which color gets put there based on the number but I know there's a way to do it using a ternary operator. Anyone know how? Thank you.

Comment: You **could** solve it with a nested ternary: `color = (x==0?BLACK:(x==1?RED:(x==.. ))..)`. But you should **not** do this. Is there any reason to enforce the use of ternary operators here?

Comment: No, there's not, I just thought it would be easier but my knowledge on ternary operators are limited. Would using a lot of if statements be ideal here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare this array:

```
Color[] colors = {  
    Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE, Color.LIGHT_GRAY, Color.GRAY,
    Color.DARK_GRAY, Color.RED, Color.PINK, Color.ORANGE, 
    Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN, Color.MAGENTA, Color.CYAN, Color.BLUE
};
```

The values of this array are all `Color` constants from `Color.java` and you can rearrange them.
Now set the color like this:

```
Color color = colors(data[r][c] % colors.length);
```

for any integer value of `data[r][c]` that is >=0.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
Map<Integer, Color> colors = new HashMap(); 
colors.put(0, Color.BLACK);
//...

function Color getColor(Integer i)
{
    return colors.containsKey(i)? colors[i] : Color.gray;
}
```

Does it can help you?

Answer (score 0):

How many colors we are talking about?

If it's a gentle number of colors just put them into a map.

```
Map<Integer, Color> colorMap = Map.of(0, Color.BLACK, 1, Color.GRAY, 2, Color.BLUE, 3, Color.RED, 4, Color.GREEN); // Java >= 9
Color color = colorMap.getOrDefault(data[r][c], Color.gray):
```

Comment: Not many, I would say about 10, might not use them all but would be nice to have.

Comment: That is okay. The number of Color is limited though. But if performance matters better use If, Switch or a pretty aligned, nested ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

You have an `int` value. And you want to obtain a `Color` for this `int` value.

You **could** use `if`-statements for that:

```
if (value == 0) color = Color.RED;
if (value == 1) color = Color.GREEN;
if (value == 2) color = Color.BLUE;
```

You **could** use a `switch` statement for that:

```
switch (value) {
    case 0: color = Color.RED; break;
    case 1: color = Color.GREEN; break;
    case 2: color = Color.BLUE; break;
}
```

You **could** use a ternary operator for that:

```
color = (value==0?Color.RED:(value==1?Color.GREEN:value==3?Color.BLUE)));
```

<sup>(don't do that....)</sup>

You **could** use a `Map` for that:

```
Map<Integer, Color> colorMap = mapWith(
    0, Color.RED, 
    1, Color.GREEN, 
    2, Color.BLUE);
...
Color color = colorMap.get(value):
```

---

But take a step back and look at what you're trying to accomplish: You want to throw your `int` value in somewhere, and obtain a `Color`. So write a function

```
private static Color colorFor(int value) {
    ...
}
```

Then, where you need the color, just write

```
Color color = colorFor(value);
```

Whether you implement the `colorFor` function using `if`, `switch`, a ternary operator or a `Map` then does no longer really matter. You can switch implementations easily.

---

"Advanced":

You could also go one step further, and pull out the actual function: When you want to convert an `int` into a `Color`, then that's exactly what is represented with an [`IntFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntFunction.html).

<sup>It might look like an abstraction overkill at the first glance. But I think it is not (otherwise I would not write it as an answer).</sup>

So you could define your `IntFunction` as you wish, and at the point in the GUI code where you have the `int` value and need the `Color`, you just to

```
Color color = colorFunction.apply(value);
```

A possible advantage of this is that you can easily switch the coloring scheme from outside, like this:

```
class YourGui {

    // Initialize with some default  
    private IntFunction colorFunction = YourGui::colorFor; 

    // The function as described above
    private static Color colorFor(int value) {
        ...
    }

    void setColorScheme(IntFunction colorFunction) {
        this.colorFunction = colorFunction;
    }
}
```

And then call

```
yourGui.setColorScheme(colorFunctionWith(CYAN, MAGENTA, YELLOW));
```

to change the cell coloring scheme.